# Linux command fails when setting output to a variable

Tags: bash, shell

I am running a shell script where I am trying to set the output of the command to a variable but it fails to pass the value of the input variable to the command that gets executed.

```
#!/bin/bash

request='<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns2:execute xmlns:ns2="http://common.ravi.com/"><arg0><clientInfoString>data-api</clientInfoString><dsAccessPassPhrase>password</dsAccessPassPhrase><dsAccessUser>user</dsAccessUser><operation>getData</operation><operationArgTypes>com.ravi.SpotMarketKey</operationArgTypes><parameters><object>rO0ABXNyAC5jb20ucmJzLmdibS5yaXNrLmRhdGEubWFya2V0LlNwb3RNYXJrZXRLZXlJbXBsAAAAAAAAAAECAAFMAAxidXNpbmVzc0RhdGV0AB9MY29tL3Jicy9nYm0vcmlzay91dGlsL2RhdGUvRHQ7eHBzcgAoY29tLnJicy5nYm0ucmlzay51dGlsLmRhdGUuRHRVdGlsJER0SW1wbIdazKHBJGu5AgABSQAEZGF0ZXhwAB+THw==</object></parameters><requestId>0_0</requestId><serializationMethod>simple</serializationMethod><serviceName>com.ravi.DataProvider</serviceName></arg0></ns2:execute></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>'

echo $request

res=`curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: text/xml'  http://localhost:8080/data-services/services/DataService -d '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns2:execute xmlns:ns2="http://common.data.risk.gbm.rbs.com/"><arg0><clientInfoString>data-api-6.8.54-SNAPSHOT_LONMW53910</clientInfoString><dsAccessPassPhrase>tim3lord</dsAccessPassPhrase><dsAccessUser>DSUser</dsAccessUser><operation>getFXRateSet</operation><operationArgTypes>com.rbs.gbm.risk.data.market.SpotMarketKey</operationArgTypes><parameters><object>rO0ABXNyAC5jb20ucmJzLmdibS5yaXNrLmRhdGEubWFya2V0LlNwb3RNYXJrZXRLZXlJbXBsAAAAAAAAAAECAAFMAAxidXNpbmVzc0RhdGV0AB9MY29tL3Jicy9nYm0vcmlzay91dGlsL2RhdGUvRHQ7eHBzcgAoY29tLnJicy5nYm0ucmlzay51dGlsLmRhdGUuRHRVdGlsJER0SW1wbIdazKHBJGu5AgABSQAEZGF0ZXhwAB+THw==</object></parameters><requestId>0_0</requestId><serializationMethod>simple</serializationMethod><serviceName>com.rbs.gbm.risk.data.market.FrontOfficeT0DataProvider</serviceName></arg0></ns2:execute></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>'`

echo $res

#fails here
res1=`curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: text/xml'  http://localhost:8080/data-services/services/DataService -d '${request}'`

echo $res1
```

When I run the above script it correctly prints the value of **res** variable with value of the variable **request** resolved, but when the command is executed where it says "fails here", in that command the variable **request** is not resolved.

I have tried many options, calling it as below but no luck.

```
$(curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: text/xml'  http://localhost:8080/data-services/services/DataService -d '${request}')
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Variables are not substituted in single quotes. Use double quotes.

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: Also, `\`...\`` is deprecated and has been for a while in `bash`.  The correct syntax for a command substitution is **`"$(...)"`**.